# Programmatically share a Word document for review

Tags: ms-word, onedrive

You are able to share Word documents in reviewer mode on OneDrive for Business. This allows recipients to suggest changes and to add comments, but not to edit the document beyond that.

You cannot share them in this mode on SharePoint. If you do, the SharePoint permissions will take precedence over them, and there is no such permission in SharePoint.

[https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/review-mode-in-word-941d357d-c9f3-4f3f-b7b0-122ed0074f30#:~:text=In%20Review%20mode%2C%20you%20cannot,suggested%20changes%20to%20the%20document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/review-mode-in-word-941d357d-c9f3-4f3f-b7b0-122ed0074f30#:%7E:text=In%20Review%20mode%2C%20you%20cannot,suggested%20changes%20to%20the%20document).

Looking at the documentation for sharing files programmatically on OneDrive, it does not mention a review option. However, I was wondering if this might be because the documentation has not been updated since the review option was introduced..?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createlink?view=odsp-graph-online